# Apparent abuse across sites.

Tags: discussion, abuse

A pair of users seem to be hitting several sites with poor or plagiarized answer, and the first user immediately accepts the answer of the second. I've notified mods on both sites, but suspect this pair are hitting more sites. Anything else I can do to help stop them?

For example:

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/34630/what-is-the-job-of-the-network-layer-under-the-osi-reference-model

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/56840/what-are-the-concepts-required-to-be-conceptual-perfect-with-computer-science?newreg=678835c225294df7b34cc123ea8d99dd

Comment: Probably related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322115/ Mods seem to be on top of it.